# Can't Link my app to admob ad server

Tags: ios, app-store, admob

So I uploaded my app to the AppStore and i put an admob banner in there. But but when search for my app in the admob website to link it i get no results, even though it's already on the AppStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long has it been live on the App Store? Just since today? It can take some hours or a day until it can "be seen" and all the links to it are working and so on... especially with the different timezones / different App Stores... So if it just went live wait a bit ...

Comment: So should i give 24-48 hours?

Comment: or just select "add your app manually"... that s what I did... I think you can link it afterwards again if I remember correct

Comment: p.s. banners are poorly paid... go for interstitials... they get you like 10x more revenue ;)

Comment: or both... banners + interstitials

Comment: Yeah, it takes a day or two for Google to refresh their search list inside the Admob website. Just keep searching, eventually it does show up. Don't worry though, your money still comes even though you haven't linked - they know the app by the id you use.

Answer (score 0):

By the way... Don t you need to create an app and the inventar (banner, interstitials...) in admob BEFORE uploading the app to the app store, because you need these adUnitIDs in the code and call it to show the banner... isn t it ???

Comment: but then you already have an app set up in admob... so don t need to create a new one??? ah ok, just want to link it afterwards yes? well just wait if the app is really new in the store... the linking isn t really doing anything else than loading the icon and the name from the store, so you don t really need that anyways...

Comment: I'm not creating a new one, i just need to link the existing app in admob to the one on the AppStore..

Comment: alright... just wait... but as I said, all it does is loading your icon and name from the store... no difference in doing it manually... just saves you time...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it took 7 days for the app to appear in the AdMob "Link your app with the App Store" view.

- V1.0 Ready for Sale on Aug 8
- App showed up in AdMob on Aug 15

It did not matter if I searched with app name, app ID or developer Name.
So I guess you just have to be patient :)

*applies also to AdWords where you have to search for your app to create a campaign.